# Retrieve Mapped Principal-Name for Security-Role in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, weblogic12c

I have my JSF Webapp up and running and security is working fine but I want to be able to tell in my code what principal a security group has been mapped to (ie. this is unrelated to the authenticated user)

My weblogic.xml looks like

```
<security-role-assignment>
  <role-name>roleA</role-name>
  <principal-name>A_Weblogic_Group</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment
```

and I want to be able to pickup that `roleA` is mapped to `A_Weblogic_Group` within the application.

The purpose behind this is to show a non authenticated user that in order to get `roleA` a user needs to apply for access to `A_Weblogic_Group`

Comment: That is not the intention of defining roles descriptively. If you want to adapt using your java-code imO it would be better to do the principal/role check in the code explicitly. For that you can use SecurityContext::isUserInRole.

Comment: Edited question to clarify.   This is to show unauthenticated users which Weblogic group they would need to apply for in order to be able to access the page.   At some level I want it to work the other way around so something like `if(!isUserInRole("RoleA") { // output message saying what group you need `